# DB Connection in html using php

Tags: php

I have a HTML page index2.html. In this page, I have a DIV which I am using to call a PHP page. The Php page has DB connection parameters, an SQL to fetch values from the DB.
However, when the PHP is called from the HTML, I am getting redirected to the PHP page. All I want is to use this stored procedure to get the data from the database.

HTML Code Snippet

```
</head>

<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="Layer0"><img src="images/Layer0.png"></div>
        <div id="Layer2"><img src="images/Layer2.png"></div>
        <div id="parceldeliveryservic"><img src="images/parceldeliveryservic.png"></div>
        <div id="Layer10">
            <form  action="insert4.php" method="post">
            <input type="image" src="images/Layer10.png"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The PHP Code Snippet:

```
<?php    include("connect.php");
//$q = intval($_GET['q']);
try {

    $proc_rate ='rtPreston';
    $proc_price = 0.0;
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=testdb", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //$sql = "GetPrice(?, ?)";
    $sql = "Call GetPrice(:input, @output_price)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    echo $proc_price;
    $stmt->bindParam(':input',$proc_rate, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    $proc_price  = $conn->query("SELECT @output_price AS output_price")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($proc_price) {          
        echo sprintf('Price for %s is %lf', $proc_rate, $proc_price['output_price']);
    }


    } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

//$conn = null; ?>
```

can you please let me know what needs to be done to display the result in the calling HTML page?

Many thanks

Comment: html can't "call" anything. it's not a programming language. it's just markup. if you want the php code output to be embedded in your html, then the html would have to do an ajax request, not just submit a form to the php script.

Comment: you could use jQuery's load function to load the remote content into the div. youre question isn't real clear though and you don't even jave javascript as a tag... what youre asking is 100% javascript

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div onclick="callPHP();">Click me!</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function callPHP() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // xmlhttp.responseText contains the result of the PHP
            alert( xmlhttp.responseText );
        }
    };

    // Call the PHP
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert4.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I tried that. the problem is the insert4.php has an 'echo' which is displayed on load of html/php instead of onclick.

Comment: All I need is, on click of a div, read values from database and display value on the calling screen or in a pop-up on the calling screen,

Comment: Then when you click the div you need to call a function that does an Ajax request of that php. The php then will do its job and it will pass the result to your function.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your latests comments.

Comment: Hi, I have used a different javascript instead of call php. This javascript replaces the target html.

Comment: I don't understand. "instead of call php"? You said you wanted to read values from the database and the display those values. How do you do that without php?